# I want to set a value in textField and not being able to change this value, only possible to insert new values. (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a registration form, when I select an especific option on input, a textField this form receive a value that cannot be changed, being able to only type with other values ​​in this textField.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a text field only the app can update (and the user can't type into), use a `TextView`.

If you want them to be able to type into it, but you want to be able to set a value and "lock" it so they can't edit it anymore, you can use an `EditText` and do `enabled = false`. That also greys out the field - if you don't want that, you can do `inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL` to prevent the keyboard from appearing.

If you want a fixed set of options that the user can choose from, you can use an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) or the [Material Components equivalent](https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus)

Comment: I would can use a text field for set a value and "lock" it, same time this text field is disponible for type in ??